# É possivel determinar o endereço de hardware do roteador?

Tags: c++, qt

Estou tentando obter o endereço de hardware de um outro equipamento (na verdade do equipamento conectado diretamente, como um modem/roteador) na mesma rede, eu consegui fazer isto:

```
foreach(QNetworkInterface netInterface, QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces())
{
    if (netInterface.flags().testFlag(QNetworkInterface::IsUp) &&
            !netInterface.flags().testFlag(QNetworkInterface::IsLoopBack))
    {
        qDebug() << netInterface.hardwareAddress();
        qDebug() << netInterface.humanReadableName();
        qDebug() << "-------------------------";
    }
}
```

Ele me retorna isto:

```
"94:39:E5:F2:AB:5D"
"Wi-Fi"
-------------------------
```

O problema é que não tenho certeza se estou retornando mesmo o endereço de hardware de um equipamento na rede ou da minha "placa" de wi-fi do computador, o que eu gostaria mesmo é de retornar o mesmo que `arp`, no meu adaptador Wi-Fi o gateway é:

```
arp -a 192.168.0.1
```

Ele retorna:

> ```
> Endereço IP           Endereço físico       Tipo
> 192.168.0.1           30-b5-c2-21-a6-66     dinâmico
> ```

Mas eu também não entendo se isto é realmente o endereço físico do roteador ou da interface no computador.

É possível retornar o endereço de hardware um equipamento?

Comment: Eu acho que a Qt não tem nenhum facilitador para comunicação raw, provavelmente vai ter que fazer direto no C++, e implementar individualmente para cada plataforma.

Comment: @Bacco foi o que imaginei, vou tentar aqui e se conseguir coloco como resposta ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução que vou lhe mostrar aqui só funciona se:

1. O programa `arp` está instalado na máquina que estiver rodando seu programa.
2. O formato da saída do `arp` for sempre a mesma (acredito que seja).

Basicamente, você roda o `arp`, captura a saída produzida por ele, e acha a informação desejada. O código abaixo foi testado no Windows porque pela saída que você mostrou parece que você está usando o Windows mesmo (me corrija se eu estiver errado). A função abaixo recebe o endereço IP como uma string e retorna o endereço físico da máquina que tem aquele endereço IP. O código está bem comentado, espero que dê pra pegar sem muita dificuldade.

```
QString obterEnderecoFisico(const QString &enderecoIP)
{
    // A classe QProcess representa um processo.
    QProcess processoARP;

    // Esecificar o nome do programa, que é arp.
    processoARP.setProgram("arp");

    // Especificar os argumentos.
    // Estou usando os mesmos argumentos que foram mostrados na pergunta.
    processoARP.setArguments(QStringList() << "-a" << enderecoIP);

    // Rodar o programa.
    processoARP.start();

    // Esperar o processo concluir.
    processoARP.waitForFinished();

    // Ler toda a saída produzida pelo processo.
    QString saida = processoARP.readAll();

    // Separar a saída por linhas.
    QStringList saidaEmLinhas = saida.split('\n');

    // Obter a linha que contém a informação desejada.
    QString linhaImportante = saidaEmLinhas.at(3);

    // Cada campo da linha importante é separado por vários espaços.
    // Precisamos obter cada campo dessa linha.
    QStringList linhaImportanteEmPartes = linhaImportante.split(' ', QString::SkipEmptyParts);

    // O endereço físico é o segundo campo.
    QString enderecoFisico = linhaImportanteEmPartes.at(1);

    // Retornar o endereço físico como uma string.
    return enderecoFisico;
} // É isso.
```

Aí você usa ele assim:

```
ui->label->setText(obterEnderecoFisico("192.168.0.1"));
```

Para alterar o texto exibido em `label` para o endereço físico da máquina que tem o endereço IP 192.168.0.1.

O código que você postou na pergunta determina o endereço físico das interfaces de rede da máquina que está rodando o seu programa (não do roteador).

**Edit:**

Esqueci de falar que para isso funcionar, você deve especificar o endereço IP de uma máquina que está na rede local, porque senão o `arp` não vai encontrar uma máquina com aquele endereço IP e a saída não estará no formato esperado. Se você quiser tornar essa função mais robusta, pode observar a saída do `arp` quando o endereço especificado não é encontrado e adaptar o código para lidar com isso. Como não sei a língua que você está usando (eu uso o Windows em inglês) não implementei essa parte, pois imagino que a saída seria diferente.

Comment: Muito obrigado Daniel, parece uma excelente solução, só vou esperar porque tenho esperanças de resolver isto somente com Qt.

Comment: E lembrando que o `arp` não retorna o equipamento do IP necessariamente, ele retorna o 1o dispositivo da rota. Se você tem um roteador no meio do caminho, pode muito bem estar recebendo o MAC do roteador (que, afinal de contas, é o MAC para qual o pacote deve ser enviado de fato para se comunicar com o tal IP). PS: é uma solução válida, dei +1 pq explicou as "armadilhas" do método. Mas espero que alguém comente de alternativas direto na camada de rede.

Comment: Concordo que essa não é a melhor abordagem. Seria melhor chamar uma função de biblioteca (ou algo assim) para acessar a informação diretamente, em vez de confiar na saída de uma aplicação externa. Acredito que Qt não fornece isso diretamente, provavelmente seria necessário usar outra biblioteca para isso.