# Algorítimo validação Mac Address

Tags: php, javascript, validação

Alguém sabe qual é o algorítimo de validação usado por esee site?

http://sqa.fyicenter.com/Online_Test_Tools/MAC_Address_Format_Validator.php

Procurei bastante pela internet porém não consegui encontrar, no site até diz como é feito porém não estou com muito tempo para estudar.. então gostaria de saber se alguém tem um pronto já..

Obs: lembrando que é a validação do Mac Address como existência, não apenas o formato.

Preferencia de linguagens: Javascript ou PHP

Comment: Nem PHP e nem Javascript tem como acessar equipamentos remotamente para detectar os endereços de MAC, nem mesmo do usuário que esta acessando a página. O unico endereço que poderia pegar seriam dos equipamentos ligados ao servidor aonde o PHP está hospedado, e isso usando o comando `arp` combinado com funções como `exec()` do PHP.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim.. é que eu recebo um Mac Address e gostaria de checar se ele é real

Comment: Com php você pode, com a API da mikrotik, mas dai você teria que ter acesso a CCR.

Comment: Só é possivel validar o formato, como disse para checar se é real teria que fazer um acesso remoto e isto não é possível e qualquer argumento de qualquer um afirmando que é possível será provavelmente uma solução não funcional ou extremante limitada.

Comment: Para validar uma entrada, somente o formato, tem muita coisa pronta e simples, uma delas é por regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acredito que para ele seja um pouco difícil, por que ele teria que ter acesso a MV para verificar os clientes PPP discados e assim recuperar o MAC deles. Creio que essa questão seja mais para rede do que programação em si.

Comment: Não tem como validar se é real. Só tem como validar se é de "marca conhecida", pq nem todos os fabricantes respeitam isso (e uns se passam por outros, principalmente no mercado de "segunda linha"). Praticamente quaisquer 6 bytes descritos em hexa são válidos.

Comment: @Bacco acredito que se ele quiser validar apenas a forma do MAC 24:A4:3C:80:EC:80 para ver se ela é "válida" segundo a norma IEEE 802 é possível. Porém não exato. Se você pegar esse MAC que eu mandei acima e testar em qualquer site (que faz o que o autor da pergunta quer), não vai funcionar. Esse mac é 5.8 (rádio) e é válido. Porém em alguns sites ele vai ser inválido.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre acho que não, como o AP disse: > *Obs: lembrando que é a validação do Mac Address como existência, não apenas o formato.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é possível detectar se o endereço de *MAC* é real, primeiro você precisa entender o que é um endereço de *MAC*, conforme wiki:

> O Endereço MAC (*Media Access Control*) é um endereço físico associado à interface de comunicação, que conecta um dispositivo à rede. O MAC é um endereço “único”, não havendo duas portas com a mesma numeração, é usado para controle de acesso em redes de computadores. Sua identificação é gravada em hardware, isto é, na memória ROM da placa de rede de equipamentos como desktops, notebooks, roteadores, smartphones, tablets, impressoras de rede, etc.

Então entenda que:

- O endereço físico só pode ser observado em LAN
- Não será publico (ou propagado para internet)
- Ele estará disponível através do mapeamento por [ARP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol)
- Você poderá conseguir tornar os dados públicos, mas isto será do equipamento especifico que você configurou e "forçou/disponibilizou"

Note que até mesmo obter ele via uma linguagem rodando em um "nível mais baixo" e em *LAN* foi um pouco complicado para mim ([É possivel determinar o endereço de hardware do roteador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160635/3635))

Fui obrigado a usar comandos como (sistema operacional Windows) para pegar todos endereços conectados na mesma rede e "visíveis":

```
arp -a
```

Saída:

```
Interface: 192.168.2.54 --- 0xe
  Endereço IP           Endereço físico       Tipo
  192.168.2.1           b8-38-61-5d-84-28     dinâmico
  192.168.2.2           48-f8-b3-bc-45-d1     dinâmico
  192.168.2.4           c0-4a-00-87-aa-d6     dinâmico
  192.168.2.150         88-51-fb-22-31-9a     dinâmico
  192.168.2.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     estático
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     estático
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     estático
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     estático
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     estático
```

Então pegar endereço de um gateway ou ip especificado:

```
arp -a 129.168.0.1
```

Saída:

```
Interface: 192.168.2.54 --- 0xe
  Endereço IP           Endereço físico       Tipo
  192.168.2.1           b8-38-61-5d-84-28     dinâmico
```

Pegar dados com ipconfig:

```
ipconfig /all
```

Saída:

```
Configuração de IP do Windows

   Nome do host. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : guilherme-PC
   Sufixo DNS primário . . . . . . . . . . . . :
   Tipo de nó. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : híbrido
   Roteamento de IP ativado. . . . . . . . . . : não
   Proxy WINS ativado. . . . . . . . . . . . . : não
   Lista de pesquisa de sufixo DNS . . . . . . : home

Adaptador de Rede sem Fio Conexão de Rede sem Fio:

   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . : router5d8428.com
   Descrição . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) WiFi Link 1000 BGN
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-26-C7-D8-E8-08
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Sim
   Configuração Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim
   Endereço IPv6 de link local . . . . . . . . : fe80::34d0:d738:4aab:83cf%14(Preferencial)
   Endereço IPv4. . . . . . . .  . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.54(Preferencial)
   Máscara de Sub-rede . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Concessão Obtida. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : quinta-feira, 17 de novembro de 2016 15:41:07
   Concessão Expira. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : domingo, 20 de novembro de 2016 03:57:36
   Gateway Padrão. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   Servidor DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   IAID de DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 184559303
   DUID de Cliente DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-8D-3F-74-3C-4A-92-4E-40-CC
   Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : fd37:267c:7d7a:1:204:dfff:fe8c:e72d
                                                 192.168.2.1
   NetBIOS em Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Habilitado
   Lista de pesquisa de sufixos DNS específicos da conexão: home
```

---

### Como é formato?

Conforme o wiki:

> A Imagem abaixo apresenta uma versão simplificada do quadro utilizado em redes locais Ethernet, conhecido como quadro Ethernet. O primeiro endereço identifica o destinatário da mensagem, ou seja, o receptor. O segundo endereço identifica o remetente, ou seja, o transmissor. Cada endereço é formado por seis bytes, permitindo teoricamente 2⁴⁸ endereços. Por exemplo, o número `00-0C-6E-3C-D1-6D` representa um endereço Ethernet no formato hexadecimal.

Você pode então validar por PHP ou JavaScript apenas o formato, usando uma [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) assim:

```
^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$
```

Um exemplo em PHP seria:

```
<?php
$mac_address = empty($_GET['mac_address']) ? '' : $_GET['mac_address'];

if (preg_match('#^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$#', $mac_address) > 0) {
     echo 'Validou!';
} else {
     echo 'Não Validou!';
}
```

> Se for aceitar letras minúsculas (pode simplesmente aplicar o [modificador `i`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), exemplo `preg_match('#^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$#i', $mac_address)`

Em JavaScript:

```js
function validaEnderecoFisico(endereco) {
    return /^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$/.test(endereco);
}

var input = document.getElementById("mac_address");
var btn   = document.getElementById("validar");

btn.onclick = function() {
    if (validaEnderecoFisico(input.value)) {
        alert("Validou");
    } else {
        alert("Não validou");
        return false;
    }
};
```

```html
<input placeholder="Digite seu endereço de MAC" type="text" id="mac_address" name="mac_address" size="26">
<button id="validar" type="button">validar</button>
```

> Se for aceitar letras minúsculas (pode simplesmente aplicar o [modificador `i`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), exemplo `/^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$/i.test(endereco)`

---

### No entanto

No entanto o @Bacco me apontou um serviço que pode ajudar a fazer isto o http://macvendorlookup.com, eles possuem uma API REST que pode lhe trazer ajudar a checar:

Por exemplo, acesse (troque pelo endereço de Mac desejado): http://www.macvendorlookup.com/api/v2/00-23-AB-7B-58-99

Ainda sim antes de usar tenha a consciência que como o [@Bacco disse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166069/algor%C3%ADtimo-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mac-address/166097#comment341738_166069):

> Não tem como validar se é real. Só tem como validar se é de "marca conhecida", pq nem todos os fabricantes respeitam isso (e uns se passam por outros, principalmente no mercado de "segunda linha"). Praticamente quaisquer 6 bytes descritos em hexa são válidos.

Alguns podem tentar se passar por outros.

Todavia um exemplo simples de uso da API com PHP seria:

```
<?php 
$enderecoMac = 'DIGITE SEU ENDEREÇO DE MAC';
$url = 'http://www.macvendorlookup.com/api/v2/' . urlencode($enderecoMac);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

$curl_err = curl_errno($ch);

if ($curl_err != 0) {
    $result = array( 'error' => 'Erro ao usar o CURL: ' . $curl_err );
} else {
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($httpCode != 200) {
        $result = array( 'error' => 'Erro ao baixar: ' . $httpCode );
    } else {
        $result = json_decode($data);
        $data = null;
    }
}

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom, de acordo com o site que você colocou o padrão do MAC pode ser:

- 6 grupos de 2 hexadecimais separados por hífen (-), Ex. **01-23-45-67-89-ab**
- 6 grupos de 2 hexadecimais separados por dois pontos (:), Ex. **01:23:45:67:89:ab**
- 3 grupos de 4 hexadecimais separados por ponto (.), Ex. **0123.4567.89ab**

Tendo em vista esse padrão podemos fazer um regex para validar todos os casos, começando pelos 2 primeiros que são praticamente iguais, só mudando o separador:

```
( ([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:-]){5} ([0-9a-fA-F]{2}) )
```

Dentro dos colchetes eu defino valores de hexadecimais válidos, seriam eles de 0 até 9 e de A até F (maiúsculo e minúsculo), logo após eu defino a quantidade que eu espero desses valores que no caso é `{2}`, em seguida eu tenho que definir o separador que pode ser dois pontos ou hífen `[:-]`, e logo após eu defino a quantidade de vezes que isso será repetido, que no caso é o número total dos grupos-1** e depois eu coloco o grupo de hexadecimais novamente, só que dessa vez sem o separador.

** **O motivo de colocar o total de grupos (que no caso é 6) menos 1 é para que o final seja aceito sem o separador, por esse motivo eu repito o conjunto no final.**

Agora vamos para o último padrão:

```
( ([0-9a-fA-F]{4}\.){2} ([0-9a-fA-F]{4}) )
```

O conjunto de hexadecimais é exatamente igual os primeiros padrões, só mudando o número de repetições para `{4}`, e em seguida eu defino um novo separador (que no caso é ponto) e repito tudo isso pelo número total de grupos - 1, e adiciono o grupo novamente sem o separador no final.

**Aqui em baixo está um exemplo do script funcionando:**

```js
document.querySelector('#mac').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  
  var status = this.value.match(/^((([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9a-fA-F]{2}))|(([0-9a-fA-F]{4}\.){2}([0-9a-fA-F]{4})))$/);

  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = status ? 'Válido' : 'Inválido';
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Digite o MAC:</label>  
  <input type="text" id="mac">
</div>

<div id="result"> </div>
```

**OBS.: `^` é igual ao inicio do regex, `$` é igual ao final do regex, e o `|` é igual ao OU lógico.**